# how to remove &nbsp; and <br> using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the following code. But it is removing only `&nbsp;` not `<br>`

```
var docDesc = docDescription.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g,"");
var docDesc1 = docDescription.replace(/(<br>)*/g,"");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Comment: Is docDescription a simple string or had it some history (like being `innerHTML()` of some DOM node)?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't parse HTML using regular expressions. Doing so on JavaScript makes even less sense; you have a parsed DOM structure, and run in context of a giant HTML parser - the browser.

Comment: @Kobi: It depends. There are situations, where you only have a serialized HTML structure (aka a string) and want to do some preprocessing before injecting it in your site (think of XSS).

Comment: Then you need a javascript html parser, same as always. I doubt this is the case though. @Shaz - I think we're missing some context here. What is `docDescription`? How does it look now, and how was it created?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can achieve removing `<br>` with CSS alone:

```
#some_element br {
  display: none;
}
```

If that doesn't fit your needs, and you want to really delete each `<br>`, it depends, if `docDescription` is really a string (then one of the above solutions should work, notably Matt Blaine's) or a DOM node. In the latter case, you have to loop through the br elements:

```
//jquery method:
$('br').remove();

// plain JS:
var brs = common_parent_element.getElementsByTagName('br');
while (brs.length) {
  brs[0].parentNode.removeChild(brs[0]);
}
```

*Edit:* Why Matt Baline's suggestion? Because he also handles the case, where the `<br>` appears in an XHTML context with closing slash. However, more complete would be this:

```
/<br[^>]*>/
```

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
var docDesc = docDescription.replace(/[&]nbsp[;]/gi," "); // removes all occurrences of &nbsp;
docDesc = docDesc.replace(/[<]br[^>]*[>]/gi,"");  // removes all <br>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var text = docDescription.replace(/(?:&nbsp;|<br>)/g,'');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try "\n"...see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
var docDesc1 = docDescription.replace(/(<br ?\/?>)*/g,"");
```

Comment: still it's removing &nbsp; but not the <br> tag.

Comment: Has the `<br>` some content, like, e.g., a class attribute?

Comment: @shaz What about the regex from the end of Boldewyn's answer, and then at the end `gi` instead of just `g`?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the input text but I've just checked that this works:

```
var result = 'foo <br> bar'.replace(/(<br>)*/g, '');
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('br');
var length = cell.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    cell[0].parentNode.removeChild(cell[0]);
}
```

It works like a charm. No need for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I using simple replace to remove `&nbsp;` and `br` tag.

#### JavaScript

```
var str = docDescription.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/\<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '');
```

#### jQuery

Remove `br` with remove() or replaceWith()

```
$('br').remove();
```

or

```
$('br').replaceWith(function() {
  return '';
});
```