# remove "&nbsp;" from script

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Currently I am having a problem with a jquery script for this customer's page that is causing a `&nbsp;` to be inserted at the end of the  container. The outcome of this is that the TR that contains the dropdown box is about 20px taller than it should be. I've traced the issue to the jquery file: jquery.styleSelect.js but I do not know what I should edit to fix this.

https://everbankstore.goincofjax.com/register.aspx

Country Dropdown list is the issue.

Comment: maybe this will help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513848/how-to-remove-nbsp-and-br-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: use $.trim to trim of whitespace at the end and beginning of strings.