# jquery clear the space in div after .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, checkbox

Checkboxes are added to div1 dynamically:

```
$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {

$("#tbl1").append('<input type="checkbox" id='+obj.firstId+' onclick=nextPopulate('+obj.firstId+'); >'); }
```

On selecting these, checkboxes are added to div2 dynamically:

```
$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {

$("#tbl2").append('<label id="chk'+firstId+'"><input type="checkbox" id="'+firstId+'-'+secondId+'" ></label>'); }
```

On unchecking the checkbox in div1, the corresponding checkboxes(lable element) created in div2 are removed :

```
if(!($('#'+firstId).is(':checked')))

    $("[id^=chk"+firstId+"]").remove();
```

Lable content is removed.But, the space is still there.If i again select in div1, checkbox in div2 will be created only after this empty space.

How can i remove the space also while removing the content.
Will refreshing/reloading the div after removing will work ?

If yes, then how is the syntax. I don't want to hit the database/call the onclick fn again. Just refresh the div to remove the space created while .remove() the label element.

Comment: Did you try $("[id^=chk"+firstId+"]").replace(/ /g,''); to remove all spaces?

Comment: `tbl1` and `tbl2` are DIVs not TABLEs, right?! Could you provide a jsfiddle which replicate your issue?

Comment: yes. they are just div's . not tables

Comment: @tilda It didn't worked

Comment: did you find the answer or still looking for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.remove()
```

will work. But make sure that all the components especially

```
<br/>
```

etc are put inside the parent element and it is removed. Then the space issue is resolved. The next append will append to the correct space in the div.

Answer (score 0):

The ".remove()" function is to remove children elements from the one which call, not to remove the one which call. So with the code below, only checkbox input element is removed, while label element still remains.

```
$("[id^=chk"+firstId+"]").remove();
```

The element calling remove() should be "tbl2", and send the parameter "[id^=chk"+firstId+"]" into the function to define the child element about to remove as below:

```
$("#tbl2").remove("[id^=chk"+firstId+"]");
```

Comment: This didn't worked. But i tried with

'$("#tbl2").has("[id^=chk"+firstId+"]").remove();'
i think this has the same logic. But the problem is that this will remove the whole div. I just want to remove the corresponding checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer will work. To remove `<br>` just do it:

```
$('br').remove(); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513848/how-to-remove-nbsp-and-br-using-javascript-or-jquery
```

If you're have more id:

```
$("[id^=chk"+firstId+"]").remove('br');
```